# arduino nodejs serial data chunked and not in synch

Tags: serial, communication, string, node.js

I'm trying to get an arduino sending data to node but with no success.
I'm connecting to an ar-drone 2.0 as in https://gist.github.com/maxogden/4152815

Here is my **Arduino** code:

```
    #include <TinyGPS++.h>
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include "Adafruit_HTU21DF.h"
    /*
      Sketch per creare json contenente
      lat,lon,data,ora,temp, hum
    */
    static const int GPS_RXPin = 16, GPS_TXPin = 10;
    static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;


    Adafruit_HTU21DF htu = Adafruit_HTU21DF();

    // The TinyGPS++ object
    TinyGPSPlus gps;

    // The serial connection to the GPS device
    SoftwareSerial ss(GPS_RXPin, GPS_TXPin);

    //JSON
    const size_t bufferSize = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(6);
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(bufferSize);
    JsonObject& oData = jsonBuffer.createObject();

    void setup()
    {
      Serial1.begin(9600);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      ss.begin(GPSBaud);
      if (!htu.begin()) {
        Serial1.println("Couldn't find Adafruit_HTU21DF!");
        while (1);
      }
    }

    void loop()
    {
      float lat = gps.location.lat();
      float lon = gps.location.lng();
      float date = gps.date.value();
      float timestamp = gps.time.value();
      float temp = htu.readTemperature();
      float hum = htu.readHumidity();

      Serial1.print(lat);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(lon);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(date);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(timestamp);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(temp);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(hum);
      Serial1.print(";\n");

      //////

      Serial.print(lat);
      Serial.print(";");
      Serial.print(lon);
      Serial.print(";");
      Serial.print(date);
      Serial.print(";");
      Serial.print(timestamp);
      Serial.print(";");
      Serial.print(temp);
      Serial.print(";");
      Serial.print(hum);
      Serial.print(";\n")

      smartDelay(1000);
      if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
        Serial1.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));
    }

    // This custom version of delay() ensures that the gps object
    // is being "fed".
    static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
    {
      unsigned long start = millis();
      do
      {
        while (ss.available())
          gps.encode(ss.read());
      } while (millis() - start < ms);
    }
```

and this my **NodeJS** code:

```
    var serialport = require('node-serialport');
    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

    var wss = new WebSocketServer({host:'0.0.0.0',port: 9999});
    var sp = new serialport.SerialPort("/dev/ttyO3", {
      parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n"),
      baud: 9600,
      buffersize: 65536
    });

    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
      ws.send('connected');
      ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
      });
      sp.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var fromArduino = chunk.toString();
        ws.send(fromArduino);
        console.log(fromArduino);
      });
    });
```

While the CSV comes out nice on Arduino IDE serial monitor, it is all messed up both on ws and node console.

[image: drone console shows messed up strings, adruino ide monitor shows them fine]

I'm using this version of NodeJS and node-serial: https://github.com/felixge/node-cross-compiler/downloads

and set ttyO3 as in https://gist.github.com/maxogden/4152815

A voltage diveder is set between drone RX and Arduino TX1 to lower signal from 5v to 1.8v.

Thanks for any help!

Lorenzo

---

**UPDATE 2 JUN 2018**
I managed to make things a little bettere with the following code:
**ARDUINO:**
        #include 
        #include 
        #include "Adafruit_HTU21DF.h"
        /*
          Sketch per creare json contenente
          lat,lon,data,ora,temp, hum
        */
        static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

```
    Adafruit_HTU21DF htu = Adafruit_HTU21DF();

    // The TinyGPS++ object
    TinyGPSPlus gps;

    void setup()
    {
      Serial1.begin(9600);
      //  Serial.begin(9600);
      if (!htu.begin()) {
        Serial1.println("Couldn't find Adafruit_HTU21DF!");
        while (1);
      }
    }

    void loop()
    {
      while (Serial1.available()) {
        gps.encode(Serial1.read());
      }
      float lat = gps.location.lat();
      float lon = gps.location.lng();
      int date = gps.date.value();
      float timestamp = gps.time.value();
      float temp = htu.readTemperature();
      float hum = htu.readHumidity();

      Serial1.print(lat);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(lon);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(date);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(timestamp);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(temp);
      Serial1.print(";");
      Serial1.print(hum);
      Serial1.print(";_");
      Serial1.println();
    }
```

**NODE JS**:

```
    var serialport = require('node-serialport');
    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

    var wss = new WebSocketServer({host:'0.0.0.0',port: 9999});
    var sp = new serialport.SerialPort("/dev/ttyO3", {
      parser: serialport.parsers.readline("_"),
      // parser: serialport.parsers.raw,
      baud: 9600,
      buffersize: 1024
    });
    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

      sp.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var fromArduino = chunk.toString();
        // console.log(fromArduino);
        ws.send(fromArduino);
        sp.flush();
      });
    });
```

Now data comes out tidy on both console and ws for most of the times: I guess the problem was the serialport buffersize.

I also removed serial software from Arduino code.

Comment: Can't see what's wrong, but a few simplifications could help you nail down the problem: 1. Get rid of SoftwareSerial and use only the hardware serial port: RX from the GPS and TX to the drone. 2. Remove the HTU and JSON code from the Arduino. 3. Remove the WebSockets code from the Node.js. 4. Use `parsers.readline("\r\n")`, as that's what `Serial.println()` sends.

Comment: since the serial monitor shows correct data, i suspect that your NodeJS code has a bug .... therefore this is not an Arduino question

Comment: @lbrutti try getting rid of your parser and directly print every received character from the UART device (`/dev/ttyO3`) to the console as fast as possible. Maybe a UART buffer is overflowing when it isn't read fast enough. Did you also try Edgar's suggestion?

Comment: Hello, i tried removing ws and software serial. Still node output comes out chunked.  I'll try to bypass parsers and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @maximilian-gerhardt: i simplified the code by removing software serial and using a smaller buffer. data comes out tidy most of the times: not always but it is accepteable for this early prototyping stage.

Comment: Hm at these speeds there should be no problem at reading it out. Could you try lowering the baud rate? (4800, 1200, 300)

Comment: Actually, yes, NodeJS serial is expected to give "chunks" your code should put it in a buffer end do the delimiting.

Comment: just one miss Sir,
only use instead "baudRate: " not a "baud".
what's a var baud Sir??? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Serial.print(lat);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(lon);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(date);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(timestamp);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(hum);
  Serial.println(";");
```

`Serial.println` will print an `\r\n` at the end ([source](https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/println)). `\r` is a "carriage return" which will move the curser back to the beginning of the line.

Since you are reading your data with a parser that looks for `\n` and removes that, you are left with a string that looks like  `[csv data..]\r`. Once you print that to console verbatim you get the behaviour you are looking at.

Replace `Serial.println(";");` by `Serial.print(";\n");` (same for `Serial1`) and see what happens.

Comment: hello, unfortunately adding "\n" char at the end of last print didn't help: both console and ws output are messed. Serial Monitor output works well as before.

Comment: @lbrutti edit your question to show the updated code, then.